# How do I have a player also be a server? [Unity 2d]

Tags: unity, multiplayer

I'm trying to make a game in Unity 2D, and I need a player to be a host because I can't afford dedicated hosting. Each client will have files that the server (and other clients) need to be able to look at through the game, and there will be a chat client. Can anyone direct me to where I need to look for this specific type of multiplayer? Everything I've seen seems to assume a dedicated host.

Answer (score 1):

Game host: The machine hosting the game
Host server: An application which manages connections and transfer of data between clients
Client: A copy of your game participating in the multiplayer game

If you wanted to do it yourself, you'd need to write a host server which is bundled with your game. When one of the clients selects 'host game' (or similar) you'll fire up the host server on the game host and have that client connect to it. From there, you'll need some way for other clients to connect to the host server (perhaps search the network for an instance of your host server and send a join game request to it)

Networking is kinda complex... Unity has a bunch of built-in networking. Taking a look at the docs is always a good starting point:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-HighLevelOverview.html